# Splitting Ansible output into 2 different strings

Tags: ansible

I have the following on my playbook:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
     msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ tapip.results }}"
     - "{{ hostname.results }}"
```

Which returns me this:

TASK [Debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "192.168.0.104"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "hostname1"
}

I would like to break the hostname and ip into 2 different strings. What is the best way to achieve this?

btw, I have also tried the following:

```
- name: Debug
  debug:
     msg: "{{ item.stdout.0 }} {{ item.stdout.1 }}"
  with_items:
     - "{{ tapip.results }}"
     - "{{ hostname.results }}"
```

Which returns this:

TASK [Debug] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "1"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item=None) => {
    "msg": "h"
}

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Try this

- name: Debug
  debug:
   msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items:

  - tapip.results
  - hostname.results

Answer (score 0):

- name: Debug
  debug:
   msg: "{{ item.stdout }}"
  with_items:

  - tapip.results
  - hostname.results